# Retrieving token value from a website using Flask API and storing token value

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So I am fairly new to flask and I am currently trying to create a flask api for a project I am working on. However, there are a couple of issues I am facing.

The 1st issue that I can't seem to solve is trying to get like a python script/function within the flask api to log on to a website? What I was thinking was store my user credentials on a separate path and use a secret key(Do not want other users to know credentials), but I am not sure if that is the best way to approach this issue.

The second issue I can't seem to solve is after I log on to the website, how can I or would I retrieve a token value if the token can be retrieved by hitting a drop down menu?

The last issue I am having a hard time with is what would be the best option for storing this token? I was originally thinking Redis would do, but I just want to know if there is a better way. Also, I plan on having this flask api/python service running in the background.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Just to give some more context, the website I am working with logs me off after a certain time after I retrieve the token.

Comment: Please give it try (code example), if there is something not working, then you post the code here. Your question is too general .

Answer (score 3):

The best way to manage login is through the [json web token](https://jwt.io/introduction)(**JWT**). Through the use of JWT it is not necessary to save any token since you can obtain all the information necessary to manage the user by extrapolating the content of the token.

To do this with flask, you can use the [Flask-JWT](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/)  library, which implements all the features needed to manage JWT, or by [Flask-JWT-Extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/).
Flask-JWT-Extended is very similar to Flask-JWT, but has more configuration options and some more functionality. For example, it allows for token refreshing.

The workflow should look like this:

1. The user logs in via the appropriate rest call, if the credentials are correct, then create the JWT and return it to the client, which takes care of saving it locally and reusing it in subsequent calls
2. For all subsequent calls that require authentication, the client will take care of specifying the JWT within the HTTP request header
3. The server rest that receives the call takes care of extrapolating the content of the token (verifying that it is valid) obtaining the necessary information.

Example taken from [Flask-JWT-Extended Basic Usage](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request

from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_jwt_extended import get_jwt_identity
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "super-secret"  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(app)


# Create a route to authenticate your users and return JWTs. The
# create_access_token() function is used to actually generate the JWT.
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    username = request.json.get("username", None)
    password = request.json.get("password", None)
    if username != "test" or password != "test":
        return jsonify({"msg": "Bad username or password"}), 401

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token)


# Protect a route with jwt_required, which will kick out requests
# without a valid JWT present.
@app.route("/protected", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    # Access the identity of the current user with get_jwt_identity
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTTP call to authenticate:

```
$ http POST :5000/login username=test password=test

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 288
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 18:10:39 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.6

{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTYxMTUxMTgzOSwianRpIjoiMmI0NzliNTQtYTI0OS00ZDNjLWE4NjItZGVkZGIzODljNmVlIiwibmJmIjoxNjExNTExODM5LCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwic3ViIjoidGVzdCIsImV4cCI6MTYxNDEwMzgzOX0.UpTueBRwNLK8e-06-oo5Y_9eWbaN5T3IHwKsy6Jauaw"
}
```

HTTP call to use protected endpoint:

```
http GET :5000/protected Authorization:"Bearer <access_token>"
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 24
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 18:12:02 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.6

{
    "logged_in_as": "test"
}
```